# new visualstate in [template10]

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, template10

How can I modify the criteria for the default visual states in template 10?

I would like to be able to distinguish between landscape mode on a phone versus a window on a PC or tablet.

NormalMinWidth is triggered by putting a phone in landscape mode. The issue is that the phone screen height in landscape mode is likely much less than a tablet or pc.

I would like to be able to have a different layout for NormalMinWidth on a phone versus a pc or tablet. For example I would like to add another visual state NormalMinWidthMinHeight that looks for a min screen height.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to implement code which allows to change the state dynamically.

For example, if you are going to change the state based on current view's orientation. You need to implement event handler for [OrientationChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation.orientationchanged) event and use [GoToState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.gotostate.aspx) method of VisualStateManager class.

Please refer to the following code sample for reference:

```xml
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AdaptiveVisualStateGroup">

            <VisualState x:Name="VisualMinWidthHeight">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="stateTextBox.Text" Value="Visual Min Width Height" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
<TextBlock x:Name="stateTextBox" Text="Current Visual State" />
```

```cs
DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().OrientationChanged += MainPage_OrientationChanged;

private void MainPage_OrientationChanged(DisplayInformation info, object args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("orientation: " + info.CurrentOrientation);
    if (info.CurrentOrientation == DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped || info.CurrentOrientation == DisplayOrientations.Landscape)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "VisualMinWidthHeight", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think a did a good job explaining the question. In the Template10 framework where does it have the code to call the VisualStateManager.GoToState ? Can I extend this? I don't want to have to put the code in each page to listen for visual state changes and call the GotoState. I though this may be in the bootstrapper but I didn't see it there.

Comment: @Sully It's ok. The above code was just a simple solution or suggestion. It's just for your reference. You could also extend [StateTriggerBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.statetriggerbase.aspx) to create your own custom triggers and use them within the StateTriggers property. The [State triggers sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlStateTriggers) tell you how to make a custom trigger. You could refer to it for details.